# I have array of object imageList where I need to achieve given pattern using flexbox

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have array of object imageList where I need to achieve given pattern using flexbox. How can we use flex-grow for the images [image]

I can achieve this pattern by using grid (...pseudo(':nth-child(1)', { gridRowStart: 1, gridRowEnd: 3 }),) but not able to get that pattern using flexbox. Please help me to get this pattern using flexbox

Current behaviour is as follows: [image]

Provided tsx and css files

Below is my code
App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
const imageList = [
{
  id: "1",
  url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
},
{
  id: "2",
  url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572276596237-5db2c3e16c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
},
{
  id: "3",
  url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80",
},
{
  id: "4",
  url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551009175-8a68da93d5f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80",
},
{
  id: "5",
  url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549880338-65ddcdfd017b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
},
{
  id: "6",
  url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883334/person-1_rfzshl.jpg",
},
{
  id: "7",
  url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883409/person-2_np9x5l.jpg",
},
{
  id: "8",
  url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg",
},
];

return (
<div className="mainWrapper">
  {imageList.map((image: any, index) => (
    <div key={image.id} className="imageWrapper">
      <img src={image.url} alt={image.url} width="100px" />
      <h4 className="heading">{image.id}</h4>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
);
};

export default App;
```

Please find the App.css

```
*{
margin: 60;
padding: 60;
}
.mainWrapper{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
gap: 30px;
margin-left: 160px;
margin-right: 160px;
}

.imageWrapper{
position: relative;
flex: 1 0 21%;
height: 200px;
}

img{
min-width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
border-radius: 20px;
}

.heading{
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
color: white;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the rendered HTML, along with the CSS, in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon has `<>`) so that others can reproduce the issue. You can reproduce [the JSX version using Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552) also, but since the question is more about HTML/CSS than React, it would probably be better to do the former.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way: main flex has direction row; each column is itself a flex, but with direction set to column.

If you want to use img's and stretch them, see object-fit ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)), or use min-height / max-height.

Relative sizing of image wrapper flex-items is done by the flex shorthand property, but can be done using min-height in percentages.

```js
const imageList = [
  {
    id: "1",
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572276596237-5db2c3e16c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551009175-8a68da93d5f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549880338-65ddcdfd017b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883334/person-1_rfzshl.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "7",
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883409/person-2_np9x5l.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "8",
    url: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg",
  },
];

class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="mainWrapper">
          {imageList.map((image, index) => {
            if (index % 2 !== 0) { return null; }
            return (
              <div key={'column' + index} className="flex-column">
                <div className="item item-1">
                  <img src={imageList[index].url} alt={imageList[index].url} width="100px" />
                  <h4 className="heading">{imageList[index].id}</h4>
                </div>
                { imageList[index + 1] ? (
                  <div className="item item-2">
                    <img src={imageList[index + 1].url} alt={imageList[index + 1].url} width="100px" />
                    <h4 className="heading">{imageList[index + 1].id}</h4>
                  </div>
                  ) : (<div className="item item-2"></div>)
                }
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.mainWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: stretch;
  gap: 20px;
}

.heading{ display: none; }

.mainWrapper .flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
  gap: 20px;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
}

.flex-column .item  {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-column img {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.flex-column:nth-child(2n) .item-2,
.flex-column:nth-child(2n + 1) .item-1 {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-column:nth-child(2n) .item-1,
.flex-column:nth-child(2n + 1) .item-2 {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how can we achieve this by using array of images?

Comment: @TruptiGaonkar , edited the answer to show it in React context with a loop like yours. In each iteration, display item-1 and item-2 wrapping imageList[index] and imageList[index + 1]. If it is a for loop, skipping a step could be done by i += 2. With Array.map we just have to not do anything if  index is not an even number ( see the index % 2 check ). Also dont forget to check that imageList[index + 1] exists.